# Regular Expression to eleminate pattern

Tags: regex

I have strings in a pattern such as

```
1. ABC No 5
2. PQR - XYZ
3. ABC (PQR)
```

Can somebody specify a regular expression which only and only removes numerical and period at the start of the screen and maintains the rest of the screen as it is?

- remove `1.` from `1. ABC No 5`
- remove `2.` from `2. PQR - XYZ`

etc.

Comment: A regular expression matches something to remove stuff you need something different. What programming language?

Comment: which language are you using..you need to specify that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a substitution expression that should work.

```
 s/^\d+\.//
```

You didn't mention what language you are using so implementation will vary depending on how the language/API exposes regex search and replace. For example, if you're processing one input line at a time, in PHP, you could do this:

```
$myVar = preg_replace('/^\d+\./', '', $myVar);
```

In java you could do this:

```
myVar = myVar.replaceFirst("^\\d+\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex`: `^[0-9]+\.`

```
^ # Matches the start of the line

[0-9]* # Matches one or more digits

\. # Matches the period (escaped as . matches anything in regex) and the space
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ cat file
1. ABC No 5
2. PQR - XYZ
3. ABC (PQR)

$ sed -E 's/^[0-9]+\. //' file
ABC No 5
PQR - XYZ
ABC (PQR)
```

Regex is not necessarily needed here however -

Using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2- file
ABC No 5
PQR - XYZ
ABC (PQR)
```

Using `Awk`:

```
$ awk -F. '{print $2}' file
 ABC No 5
 PQR - XYZ
 ABC (PQR)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Perl

```
$cadena ="1111. ABC No 5";
$cadena =~ s/^[\d\.]+//;
print $cadena;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
while(<>) {
  print $_ unless /[^-0-9]/
}
```